# Mysql server slower on Ubuntu server than Ubuntu desktop

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I want to test the mysql-server (5.7.22 on both installed using apt-get) speed on Ubuntu desktop vs Ubuntu server for a school project. I have a script that runs 3 sql queries, each 10000 times and writes the time it took for each query to finish in a file. On average my queries took about 10 milliseconds on Ubuntu desktop (18.04 64bit) but they take 2.5 seconds per query on my Ubuntu server (18.04 64bit) which makes it take forever and uncomparable to the other resultset. I have no clue why this is the case, they are on the same disk and have the same resources (CPU, RAM and saved on the same SSD) they are both running in Virtualbox (but I test them with only 1 machine running at a time).

I am using the sample 'employees' database from mysql.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

AantalQ=3 #Amount of queries.
AantalHH=10000  #How often to repeat the queries.

for ((i=1; i<=AantalQ; i++)); do #Loop through queries.
    for ((j=0; j<AantalHH; j++)); do #Repeat the current query.
        echo "Query$i uitvoering $j" #Progress.
        time (mysql --login-path=local employees < "Query$i.sql" > null) 2>> tijd.csv
    done
done

sed -i.bak '/real/!d' tijd.csv #Delete all lines without 'real'.
tr -dc "0-9\n" <tijd.csv >temp.tmp && mv temp.tmp tijd.csv #Delete everything except for numbers.
sed -i.bak 's/^0*//' tijd.csv #Delete leading zeros.
```

My queries:

1.

```
USE employees;
SELECT SUM(salaries.salary),
  AVG(salaries.salary),
  MAX(salaries.salary),
  COUNT(employees.emp_no)
FROM employees
JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no;
```

2.

```
USE employees;
SELECT *                        #208734 records
FROM employees
JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no
WHERE first_name LIKE 'A%' AND salary > 2500;
```

3.

```
USE employees;
SELECT concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as fullname, de.from_date, de.to_date, dept_name, dm.from_date, dm.to_date, title, salary
FROM employees e
JOIN salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
JOIN titles t ON e.emp_no = t.emp_no
JOIN dept_emp de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no
JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept_no
JOIN dept_manager dm ON d.dept_no = dm.dept_no

WHERE first_name LIKE 'B%' OR first_name LIKE 'C%' OR first_name LIKE 'Z%'AND last_name LIKE 'C%' OR last_name LIKE 'O%' OR last_name LIKE 'X%';
    #WHERE DATE(birth_date) BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '1980-01-01'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't be the same setup on both machines.  Your Ubuntu Server MySQL is not setup correctly.

Comment: I already reinstalled the mysql-server on both machines and did everything exactly the same way to set everything up but got the same results. Is there a difference to how the server should be set up on the server vs the desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

install mysqltuner by doing a

```
apt-get install mysqltuner
```

and run it on each virtual machine.  Hopefully it will show you what is difference during the analysis process. Good Luck!

Comment: @max  If you could take the time to post the information requested on May 8, 2018 for BOTH the desktop and server, we will find some differences for you.  Yes, I know it will take time and remember pastebin.com has 500MB limit per post, unless you are a pastebin PRO member (then the limit is 10GB).